# Finding a sub rectangle with maximum sum

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms

Given a $n \times n$ matrix filled with positive or negative numbers, find a sub rectangle with maximum sum and output the sum.

There's a well-known algorithm which runs in $O(n^3)$, but can the complexity be improved any further?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [Tadao Takaoka, Efficient Algorithms for the Maximum Subarray Problem by Distance Matrix Multiplication, In Electronic Notes in Theoretical Computer Science, Volume 61, 2002, Pages 191-200](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1571066104003135) you can find a simplified algorithm (the original is by Tamaki and Tokuyama) that runs in sub-cubic time for $m \times n$ arrays:

$$O ( m^2 n (\log \log m / \log m)^{1/2}) $$

From the paper: *... Bentley's algorithm is cubic and the Tamaki-Tokuyama algorithm is sub-cubic for a nearly  square array. Their algorithm is heavily recursive and complicated. We simplify the latter algorithm, and achieve sub-cubic time for any rectangular array ...*

They also give a more practical algorithm whose expected time is close to quadratic for a wide range of random data.